# How to find same text which exists in CoreData more than once

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a list of names in `CoreData` and here I am loading in `UITableView` and I have a option to edit those names. Lets suppose I have 3 names "John", "Jack", "joo" first have edited "John" and I don't want to change save with same text like "John" but if i have entered "Jack" which already exists in list, this time I have to give an alert like "this name already exists"

```
if([dbWrapper checkMyListNameExist:currentgoalType mylistName:_txtView.text])
            {
                isNameValid = YES;
                CustomAlert *alert = [[CustomAlert alloc] initWithTitle:@"" message:@"Please choose a different name" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitle:@""];
                [alert showInView:self.view];
                [_txtView resignFirstResponder];
                CGRect frame = _bgView.frame;
                frame.origin.y = frame.origin.y + 100;
                if(isFrameUp)
                {
                    [UIView beginAnimations: nil context:NULL];
                    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
                    isFrameUp = NO;
                    _bgView.frame = frame;
                    [UIView commitAnimations];
                }
                return;
            }
```

Comment: You should maintain your table row as count of your coredata count.then after you select table row then use NSPredicator to identify entered text is there in all row's except your selected row.

Comment: for example you select row 0->ramesh so you selected position 0 in coredata array Then start checking  total coredata array except row 0 in coredata

Comment: thanks Ajay but how we can find can help thourgh my code

Answer (score 0):

You have to make NSFetchRequest with NSPredicate and fetch objects from CoreData which meet your requirements. In your case you want to count all objects which has a name equal to candidate name.

After you create proper NSPredicate use:

```
NSUInteger count = [moc countForFetchRequest:request error:&err];
```

If count > 0 - you already have a name in your CoreData

To exclude current object use

```
NSPredicate * exludePredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF != %@", yourCurrentEditedObject]; 
NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:nameFilterPredicate, exludePredicate].
```

Or even simpler, keep an original name before edit and after edit - if they are equal - save nothing.

Comment: NSFetchRequest *FetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *Entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"TblMylist"   inManagedObjectContext:_managedContext];    [FetchRequest setEntity:Entity]; NSPredicate *Predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"goaltype == %d AND wordlistgroupname == %@",goaltype,listname];[FetchRequest setPredicate:Predicate];
    NSError *error;NSArray *FetchedObjects = [_managedContext executeFetchRequest:FetchRequest error:&error];
    if([FetchedObjects count] > 0)
        return YES;
    else return NO;

Comment: So what is exactly the problem ? From your question it looked like you don't know how to find duplicates

Comment: this is how i am feaching from core data

Comment: my problem is exactly.. if i edit "jack" and again i have give a same name "jack" this time no need show alert.but if i edit "jack" then i have given john which is alredy existed in core data that time only i have to give alert